# Specify DLLs for an exe launched with Process.Start?

Tags: c#, dependencies, exe, process.start

I'm trying to launch an executable with Process.Start().  When the exe has no DLL dependencies, it works fine.  However, when I need to include 2 DLLs, it doesn't work.  I've tried setting the WorkingDirectory, and have verified that the 2 required DLLs are present there.  Any ideas?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "memcached.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;  //not shown           
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

try
  {
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
      {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
      }
  }
    catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);  // never gets here
  }
```

This is [code based on the Windows Azure Memcached Solution Accelerator](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/winazurememcached).  When memcached can't launch, a dialog box is displayed.  Unfortunately you can't see this when the code is running remotely in the cloud.

Comment: I would have thought a Process.Start() would be too hard to secure in azure and they would have disabled it? Doesn't Azure provide you with a magic cache as part of it's API?  Note that I don't know and I'm curious.

Comment: Spence: Microsoft AppFabric Cache, aka "Velocity", is their distributed cache but it doesn't work in Azure yet.  These days you can run whatever you want in Azure as long as it doesn't require administrator privileges.

Comment: Ugh.  When you program in the cloud, how do you know where the rain comes from?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem trying to start another process that needed a DLL and couldn't find it. The solution was pretty simple in my case, a missing '\'.

```
procInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\filedir"; //won't work
procInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\filedir\" ; //would do the trick

procInfo.WorkingDirectory = Enviroment.CurrentDirectory; //== "C:\filedir", that won't work either
procInfo.WorkingDirectory = Enviroment.CurrentDirectory + '\\'; // would work.
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you are setting the `WorkingDirectory` to the current directory of the current process (which could be anywhere, not necessarily the directory containing your program).  Try setting the working directory to the directory containing the exe you want to start.

Also, have you verified that the DLLs are with `memcached.exe` (or in the place required by the `memcached.exe`)?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  `Environment.CurrentDirectory` is E:\approot, and I've verified that both the exe and the DLLs are present there.

Comment: Ok.  I wasn't sure if meant the DLLs were with your program, or with the exe you want to start.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your .EXE file and that referenced assemblies in same place, and to define your `WorkingDirectory.WorkingDirectory` to that folder. This probably will work fine.

One *extreme* alternative is to strong name that references assemblies (DLL) and to register them into GAC.

You should exhaust all other alternatives before think about this option.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think we can install DLLs into the GAC in Azure.  Yes, I have put the exe & DLLs into the same folder.  Thanks for your thoughts though.  Since it seems straightforward, I wonder if I'm actually experiencing a different problem from what I initially thought.